# Windows 8.1 after migration to SSD looks for components on the wrong drive

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, operating-systems, migration

weird situation: after I have migrated my Win 8.1 OS to new SSD I can't run certain operations as for example "Create Recovery Drive".

Every time I try to start that I get error message

```
"Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file."
```

and in the bar of the message I see path starting with

```
"D:\Users\....".
```

My OS runs on drive C:

The same happens for few other operations as well.

I used Samsung Magician for the migration as it came with the new SSD from Samsung. Everything else seems to work alright, for now.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Ugh, something went terribly wrong, is your system disk D: instead of C: after migration?

Answer (score 0):

1. run cmd as admin
2. Input

> "SFC / SCANNOW"

all uppercase and without quotes, this will try to repair the corrupted system files.

3. Reboot your system to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your search indexes are still pointing at the old drive.  Try clearing your search history so that it can rebuild them and point to your new drive.

1. Launch the "PC Settings" app from the start menu.  You'll probably have to browse to it, as type-to-search will likely point you to your D: drive rather than your C: drive.
2. Choose "Search and apps" from the menu on the left.
3. Hit the "Clear" button under "Clear search history" and click through the confirmation dialog.

You may have to restart Windows before the changes kick in.